# 68k Assembly: ORG $2000 and DS.L functionality

Tags: assembly, 68000, easy68k

I have a 68k Assembly program that calculate the average of values in a 3x3 array's diagonal and stores it.

```
    ORG    $1000
START:                  ; first instruction of program

* Put program code here

        move.w      n,d6        ; d6 = 0000 0003
        clr.l       d7          ; sum = 0
        move.w      #2,d4       ; size of element 0000 0002
        mulu.w      d6,d4       ; n times size of element 
                                ; d4 0000 0006
        movea.l     #A,a0       ; address of the array

loop    tst.w       d6          ; if (n == 0)
        beq         done        ; go to done else go to next instruction
        subq.w      #1,d6       ; 3 - 1, 2 - 1, 1 - 1, done
        add.w       (a0)+,d7    ; a0 address is incremented 2 bytes since its word length
                                ; content of address a0 is stored in d7
                                ; d7 = 0000 0001, 0000 0005, 0000 0009

        add.l       d4,a0       ; increment for diagonals which in 3x3 = 3 position = 6 bytes
                                ; a0 = 02 + 06 = 08, 08 + 06 = 10 hex = 16 decimal
        bra         loop        ; restart loop until condition is met

done    divu.w      n,d7        ; now d7 has the sume of diagonals
                                ; d7 = 1 + 5 + 9 = 15
                                ; 15 / 3 = 5
                                ; result is stored in d7 = 5    
        move.l      d7,store    ; d7 is stored in 



    SIMHALT             ; halt simulator

* Put variables and constants here

A       dc.w    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
n       dc.w    3

        org     $2000           ; what does this do?
store   ds.l    1               ; notice its long word    

    END    START        ; last line of source
```

I understand everything going on in this code except for the lines:

```
org     $2000           ; what does this do?
store   ds.l    1       ; notice its long word
```

Can someone explain to me in simple words, what org "$2000" is doing and "ds.l 1". What is the DS command doing and what does the number 1 after it, represents?

I check the memory block d7 value is stored in address 0000 2000 but again what does this have to do with the number 1 in front of DS.L and what does ORG do in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org $2000` just sets the current address to `$2000` meaning the following `store` label will be at `$2000`. For whatever reason, that's where the result is expected. `ds.l` reserves the given number of longwords, `1` in this case. The `move.l d7,store` will write `d7` there. This is presumably in the specification for this task, that is something like "*produce a longword result at address $2000*".

Answer (score 1):

`ORG` defines the memory address from which the next values start

[`ds.l`](http://68k.hax.com/DS) reserves long words without initializing them

In this case one long word is reserved at $2000 without assigning any specific value to it. `store` is understood as a pointer to this location.

I do recommend writing *68k org* or *68k ds.l* into your favorite search engine and notice that the information is quickly available.